# How to pass object in s:iterator tag struts to post ajax jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, struts2

I want to send a object in s:iterator to request data in post ajax jquery like :

- at jsp : `<s:iterator value="arrApi" var="api">`
- at java : `private Apis testApi;`
- at event onclick button : `onclick="javascript:test('${api}'); return false"`
- at javascript function with post ajax jquery :

```js
function test(api){
    var url = "ApiAction?test=test";
    var requestData = {testApi: api};
    $.post(url, requestData, function(data,status){
        alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
    }); 
    return false;
}
```

But at function in java i can't get data of `testApi` variable. If i try change object `testApi` by String variable `private String name;` (a property of Apis):

```
public class Apis{
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String method;
}
```

Change parameter onclick like : `onclick="javascript:test('${api.name}'); return false"`. And at function javascript change var to map variable java : `var requestData = {name: api};`. Then it's ok, i can get data `name` in java function.

How can i pass object data to post ajax jquery ? Larger question, how can pass **arr object** like above example is `arrApi` of s:iterator tag (because in s:iterator tag contains input form) like :

[image]

Comment: You can pass strings.

Comment: But that's dynamic array

Comment: It's not clear to me what the issue is. You're the one that's setting it to a single API--send an array.

Comment: You mean send an array property of object ? But arrApi is dynamic array (init from db when load jsp first).